# Can someone please explain why my print method isn't working?

Tags: java, printing

I am trying to call a `getName` and `getBalance` method from another class called `Account` in my printbalances method in class bank. but it is not working it prints null after inputing customer and balance. can someone explain why and how to fix it? I can honestly say I don't know why it is not working.

Here is the class that is calling it:

```
class Bank {

    ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner q;
    String name;
    double balance;

    private Account account = new Account(name, balance);

    public void enterCustomers() {

        System.out.println("Enter customer names or press q to quit entering names: ");

        while (true) {
            String name;
            double balance;
            System.out.print("Enter a customer name: ");
            name = input.next();

            if ("q".equals(name)) { //tried using == to break but wouldnt work so tried .equals since comparing strings and works
                break;
            }

            System.out.print("Enter the opening balance : ");
            balance = input.nextDouble();
            accounts.add(new Account(name, balance));

        }
    }

    public void printBalances() {

        System.out.println("==========================");
        System.out.println("Customer            Balance");
        System.out.println("==========================");
        System.out.println(account.getName() + account.getBalance());

    }
```

and here is the classs where the get methods are stored:

```
class Account {

    private String name;
    private double balance;

    public Account(String name, double balance) {

        this.name = name;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return name;

    }

    //public void setName(String name) {
    //  this.name = name;
    //}
    public double getBalance() {

        return balance;

    }

    //public void setBalance(double balance) {
    //  this.balance = balance;
    //}
    public void deposit(double amount) {

        balance += amount;

    }

    public void withdrawal(double amount) {

        if (balance >= amount) {
            balance -= amount;
        } else {
            System.out.println(" Insufficient Balance. ");
        }

    }

}
```

The output it gives me is this:

```
Enter customer names or press q to quit entering names: 
Enter a customer name: john
Enter the opening balance : 200
Enter a customer name: mike
Enter the opening balance : 2
Enter a customer name: q

==========================
Opening account balance
==========================
Customer            Balance
==========================
null0.0

(1)deposit (2)withdraw (0)quit
```

I dont know why `null 0.0` appears and can someone explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are initializing `account` like this:

```
private Account account = new Account(name, balance);
```

But here `name` and `balance` are not initialized, so they are `null` and zero respectively by default. It looks more like you want to print the name and balance of a specific `Account` object, so I would pass it as an argument to `printBalances`:

```
public void printBalances(Account account) {

    System.out.println("==========================");
    System.out.println("Customer            Balance");
    System.out.println("==========================");
    System.out.println(account.getName() + " : " + account.getBalance());

}
```

Or if you wanted to print every balance in the `accounts` `ArrayList`:

```
public void printBalances() {
    System.out.println("==========================");
    System.out.println("Customer            Balance");
    System.out.println("==========================");
    for(Account account : accounts) {
        System.out.println(account.getName() + " : " + account.getBalance());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are there any more references to `account`?

You are likely overriding it at some point because it has a name of `null` and a balance of `0.0`